# discord.py bot crashes randomly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using discord.py v0.16.12, and I occasionally get this traceback that crashes the bot. The token is present and valid even though the traceback leads you to believe otherwise.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 94, in <module>
    bot.run(auth.get('discord', 'TOKEN'))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 491, in start
    yield from self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 448, in connect
    yield from self.ws.poll_event()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 431, in poll_event
    yield from self.received_message(msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 390, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 256, in parse_message_update
    message.embeds = data['embeds']
KeyError: 'embeds'
```

Comment: Hi, please include a runnable snippet of code in your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're using discord.py 0.16.12 which is more than 2 years old. The latest version is apparently 1.3.1. I don't want to say that chances are high outdated versions either had bugs or the API has changed and they're not compatible anymore, but it is pretty high.

Comment: Can you include the code? Also, I would try checking if the API is up to date.

Comment: @Masklinn yeah that's a likely possibility I want to update it but it would require basically rewriting the whole repo lol.
Here is the repo https://github.com/jcsumlin/Hilda-Bot
I have a feeling its something to do with the on_message function but its unclear as the traceback doesn't really give me much info.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the stack trace, the first line is showing you the origin of the call (`bot.run(...)`) that resulted in the error, but the actual error and faulting line of code are at the bottom. `KeyError: 'embeds'`.  The traceback does not imply that the token is missing or invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This was [an issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2195) that [was fixed](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/f84219c2b2f94133ea1d7989c50547042dc7145e) with v1.2.0 of discord.py.

v0.16.12 is an outdated version of discord.py that isn't supported anymore.
You should look into [migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).